# Adding a Maven dependency to Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: scala, maven-2, netbeans-6.9

I seem to be having a problem with Netbeans 6.9.1. (The same problem occurs in Netbeans 7.0, but I can't use it because of other problems.)

- I am writing a project using Maven and add a dependency to the `pom.xml` file (e.g.: junit).
- I right click the "Libraries" item in the project tree and select "Download missing dependencies".
- I try to add the annotation `@Test` in the editor window and it gets flagged as unknown.
- I add an `import org.junit.Test`
- Netbeans then complains that "junit is not a member of org".

I am using the Scala plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same problem not only for Maven projects, but also for Ant-based ones. In the most cases, "Reset Scala Plugin" + reopening the file works for me. When it doesn't help (sigh), I'm restarting the IDE.

Also, you can clone https://github.com/dcaoyuan/nbscala.git, and build from sources (if that's a bug in the plugin, there's a good chance that it's already fixed in the master).

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the Scala Plugin reset first (:-)).